# Avoid ruby script requiring a folder with 777

Tags: permissions, ruby

I am running a ruby script, that contains

```
unless File.writable?(".")
    problems << ["Directory /path/to/htdocs needs write access"]
```

the problem is, only if I set

chmod 777 /path/to/htdocs

it works, yet I read you shouldn't 777 anything really.

So how can I circumvent this problem for the code to run with 755 instead of 777?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is never a need to use 777. You can however find out what the problem is:

- if it works with 777 and not 770 you are using an unknown user in your environment. Change to a known user and it will work using 770.
- if it works with 770 and not with 700 you are using an unknown group in your environment. Same fix: set the environment to a known group.

So apache2, nginx or whatever you use to execute scripts will have a user and a group set in its configuration. Find user and group used and change your script to that user and group and all you will need is 700 or 750.